# Create a cookie that lasts until the browser is closed(Session Cookie?)

Tags: python, browser, cookies

I am familiar with assigning, creating cookies in Python. But I am unsure how to create a cookie that will last until the current browser session is closed(so I have a very rudimentary way of telling when the user is **returning** to my website).

So which cookie header do I set to make sure the cookie will expire/delete when the browser is closed in Python? Do I use the SimpleCookie object or another object for this?

This thread says I set the cookie_lifetime flag/header in PHP, but what about for python? http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/595383-how-declare-cookie-will-destroy-after-browser-closed

Would this create a cookie that expires on closing of the browser?

```
cookie  = Cookie.SimpleCookie()
cookie["test"] = "MYTEST"
cookie["test"]['expires'] = 0 # or shd I set the max-age header instead?
print str(cookie) + "; httponly"
```

Comment: I think you don't even need to set `expires` at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just leave out the "expires" value altogether, i.e. don't set it to anything.  See the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Expires_and_Max-Age) for details:

> Set-Cookie: made_write_conn=1295214458; path=/; domain=.foo.com
>
> [...]
>
> The second cookie made_write_conn does not have expiration date, making it a session cookie. It will be deleted after the user closes his/her browser

In Python:

```
In [11]: from Cookie import SimpleCookie

In [12]: c = SimpleCookie()

In [13]: c['test'] = 'MYTEST'

In [14]: print c
Set-Cookie: test=MYTEST
```

Answer (score 1):

Mack,

Your answer looks correct to me.  Setting "expires" = 0 on the Morsel object should do what you want.  Have you tested it?

Looks like max-age is not supported by IE:

http://mrcoles.com/blog/cookies-max-age-vs-expires/

Comment: Yes, IE don't support max-age, but simply excluding expires (and the same with max-age) should make SimpleCookie create a session cookie, as that post says, "if you set neither—the cookie will last until you close your browser"