# Understanding Few Cookie "Parameter"

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I am not sure about below 2 cookie `property` (`session` & `storeId`). How to assign them and how to set value for them.

```
{
    "domain": "localhost",  
    "expirationDate": 1395835493.034348,
    "hostOnly": true,
    "httpOnly": true,
    "name": "token",
    "path": "/",
    "secure": false,
    "session": false,    /* What does session option mean here & how to assign them. */
    "storeId": "0",      /* What does storeId mean here & how to assign them. */
    "value": "6e5ef234b7f34fd265f011ab80fc0cff"
}
```

I know about rest `cookie property`, but just not clear about `session` & `storeId`.

Can someone please explain.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are using chrome extension API to print this info.

storeid and session attribute for a cookie would be due to Chrome extension API. RFC for Cookie does not have these.

session  - True if the cookie is a session cookie, as opposed to a persistent cookie with an expiration date.
storeId  - The ID of the cookie store containing this cookie, as provided in getAllCookieStores().

From:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies

**Update**: Ignoring expires value will make it a session cookie. [Create a cookie that lasts until the browser is closed(Session Cookie?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5670419/create-a-cookie-that-lasts-until-the-browser-is-closedsession-cookie)

Comment: How to make/set `cookie` as a `session cookie` ?

Comment: Ignoring expires value will make it a session cookie.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5670419/create-a-cookie-that-lasts-until-the-browser-is-closedsession-cookie